# SSAS MDX : Appending columns from different result sets

Tags: ssas, mdx

I've started working with SSAS cubes recently. I have a requirement where I need results from different date ranges to be shown side-by-side, for the required measures. Something like :

```
                         Last 7 Days     Last 6 Months   Last Full Year
Internet Sales Amount        X                Y               Z
Reseller Sales Amount        X                Y               Z
```

Any pointers towards a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Venu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm only guessing (and maybe my syntax is wrong), but perhaps something like this:

```
WITH
  MEMBER [MYTIME][Last 7 Days] AS 
    'Aggregate(LastPeriods(7, StrToMember(Format(CDate(),"YYYY-MM-DD"))))'
  [MYTIME][Last 6 Months] AS
    'Aggregate(LastPeriods(6, StrToMember(Format(CDate(), "YYYY-MM"))))'
  [MYTIME][Last Full Year] AS
    'Aggregate(LastPeriods(12, StrToMember(Format(CDate(), "YYYY-MM"))))'
SELECT
  {[MYTIME].[Last 7 Days], [MYTIME].[Last 6 Months], [MYTIME][.Last Full Year]} ON COLUMNS
  {[Internet Sales Amount], [Reseller Sales Amount]} on ROWS
FROM MYCUBE
```

That one gets 12 months for the the full year, but if you mean calendar year, you'll want to do something different.

Comment: Can we specify our own dimension in the 'WITH MEMBER' clause? (Like [MYTIME] in your example?). I got an error saying 'MYTIME' wasn't a dimension
I changed [MYTIME] to [Measures], but since the rows were measures themselves, that also threw an error because the same dimension was used in different hierarchies.

Comment: I don't think you can't add your own dimension in a WITH clause.  What you should do is substitute your actual time dimension for [MYTIME].

Comment: I've got the desired result with a few modifications. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.